# How can I replace Activity scoped dependencies with mocks using Dagger2

Tags: android, unit-testing, dependency-injection, dagger, dagger-2

I have a scoped dependency in my Activity and I want to test that activity with some mocks. I have read about different approach that suggest to replace Application component with a test component during the test, but what I want is to replace the Activity component.

For example, I want to test the Activity against mock presenter in my MVP setup.

I believe that replacing component by calling setComponent() on Activity will not work, because Activity dependencies already injected via field injection, so during the test, real object will be used.

How can I resolve this issue? What about Dagger1? Is it has the same issue?

Comment: I've done this once http://stackoverflow.com/a/30736436/2413303 but with enough modules, this becomes hell to maintain (because every module becomes parametric and you need to explicitly create all of them with the right provider)... I'm trying to figure out a better solution. The problem is that you cannot extend modules in Dagger2, even though you did have the option to use `overrides=true` for a module in Dagger1.

Answer (score 2):

**Injecting the Component**

First, you create a static class to act as a factory for your Activity. Mine looks a little like this:

```
public class ActivityComponentFactory {

    private static ActivityComponentFactory sInstance;

    public static ActivityComponentFactory getInstance() {
        if(sInstance == null) sInstance = new ActivityComponentFactory();
        return sInstance;
    }

    @VisibleForTesting
    public static void setInstance(ActivityComponentFactory instance) {
        sInstance = instance;
    }

    private ActivityComponentFactory() {
        // Singleton
    }

    public ActivityComponent createActivityComponent() {
        return DaggerActivityComponent.create();
    }
}
```

Then just do `ActivityComponentFactory.getInstance().createActivityComponent().inject(this);` inside your Activities.

For testing, you can replace the factory in your method, before the Activity is created.

**Providing mocks**

As @EpicPandaForce's answer makes clear, doing this the *officially-supported* way currently involves a lot of boilerplate and copy/pasted code. The Dagger 2 team need to provide a simpler way of partially overriding Modules.

Until they do though, here's my unnoficial way: *Just extend the module*.

Let's say you want to replace your ListViewPresenter with a mock. Say you have a PresenterModule which looks like this:

```
@Module @ActivityScope
public class PresenterModule {

    @ActivityScope
    public ListViewPresenter provideListViewPresenter() {
        return new ListViewPresenter();
    }

    @ActivityScope
    public SomeOtherPresenter provideSomeOtherPresenter() {
        return new SomeOtherPresenter();
    }
}
```

You can just do this in your test setup:

```
ActivityComponentFactory.setInstance(new ActivityComponentFactory() {
    @Override
    public ActivityComponent createActivityComponent() {
        return DaggerActivityComponent.builder()
                .presenterModule(new PresenterModule() {
                    @Override
                    public ListViewPresenter provideListViewPresenter() {
                        // Note you don't have to use Mockito, it's just what I use
                        return Mockito.mock(ListViewPresenter.class);
                    }
                })
                .build();
    }
});
```

...and it *just works*!

Note that you don't have to include the `@Provides` annotation on the `@Override` method. In fact, if you do then the Dagger 2 code generation will fail.

This works because the Modules are just simple factories - the generated Component classes take care of caching instances of scoped instances. The `@Scope` annotations are used by the code generator, but are irrelevant at runtime.

Comment: I totally did not think of that at all. I guess anonymous subclasses aren't checked for override, while real ones are? That is funny because that would imply that this is a bug, but in reality it should have been a feature from the start.

Comment: It doesn't matter if the class is named or not - the code generator looks for the presence of the `@Provides` annotation on methods. If that isn't present, it ignores them. I would definitely consider this approach a temporary hack until some official guidance/extra features are released. Some complex scenarios might run into issues (but I haven't encountered any yet).

Comment: Wait, so you can override methods in modules as long as you don't specify a second `@Provides` annotation?

Comment: Yes, but you can't alter the `@Provides` contract - e.g. if the original method is tagged `@ApplicationScope @Named("foo")` then any overrides will also take the same contract.

Comment: ....maybe I was just stupid and assumed that you need to specify the `@Provides` method on the subclassed module methods as well, and otherwise extending the module works perfectly fine...? I'll feel like a dunk. I should have tested that. I remember Dagger2 telling me that I cannot extend modules, but I didn't try not having the annotation in the subclass...

Comment: If it makes you feel any better, I missed it too. My first stab at this involved creating a partial mock of the submodule! :)

Comment: About the ActivityComponentFactory solution.
I expected something "nicer" but it works.

Comment: I've found a cleaner solution for the static component factory. Check this article: http://blog.sqisland.com/2015/04/dagger-2-espresso-2-mockito.html

Answer (score 0):

You cannot override modules in Dagger2 [**EDIT: you can, just don't specify the `@Provides` annotation on the mock**), which would obviously be the proper solution: just use the `builder().somethingModule(new MockSomethingModule()).build()` and be done with it!

If you thought mocking is not possible, then I would have seen two possible solutions to this problem. You can either use the modules to contain a pluggable "provider" that can have its implementation changed *(I don't favor this because it's just too verbose!)*

```
public interface SomethingProvider {
    Something something(Context context);
}

@Module
public class SomethingModule {
    private SomethingProvider somethingProvider;

    public SomethingModule(SomethingProvider somethingProvider) {
        this.somethingProvider = somethingProvider;
    }

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    public Something something(Context context) {
        return somethingProvider.something(context);
    }
}

public class ProdSomethingProvider implements SomethingProvider {
    public Something something(Context context) {
        return new SomethingImpl(context);
    }
}

public class TestSomethingProvider implements SomethingProvider {
    public Something something(Context context) {
        return new MockSomethingImpl(context);
    }
}

SomethingComponent somethingComponent = DaggerSomethingComponent.builder()
    .somethingModule(new SomethingModule(new ProdSomethingProvider()))
    .build();
```

Or you can bring the provided classes and injection targets out into their own "metacomponent" interface, which your `ApplicationComponent` and your `TestApplicationComponent` extend from.

```
public interface MetaApplicationComponent {
    Something something();

    void inject(MainActivity mainActivity);
}

@Component(modules={SomethingModule.class})
@Singleton
public interface ApplicationComponent extends MetaApplicationComponent {
}

@Component(modules={MockSomethingModule.class})
@Singleton
public interface MockApplicationComponent extends MetaApplicationComponent {
}
```

The third solution is to just extend the modules like in @vaughandroid 's answer. Refer to that, that is the proper way of doing it.

As for activity scoped components... same thing as I mentioned here, it's just a different scope, really.

Comment: It's not officially supported, but you *can* extend Modules. Just extend the class and override the provider methods! This definitely shouldn't be done in production code, but I've found it works well for inserting mocks for tests.

Comment: @vaughandroid my goal is to replace the dependencies provided by field injection with `void inject(Something something);` call by somehow swapping out the modules, does that allow that? The two I mentioned here do, and I think the second one is the cleaner solution.

Comment: It doesn't make a difference whether you use constructor, field, or method injection. I haven't run into any pitfalls with it yet, though I'm sure there are some.

Comment: I have written my own answer here http://stackoverflow.com/a/32330072/213727 which includes an example and a brief explanation.

Answer (score 0):

I've found the following post that solves the problem:
http://blog.sqisland.com/2015/04/dagger-2-espresso-2-mockito.html

You need first to allow to modify the component of the activity:

```
@Override public void onCreate() {
  super.onCreate();
  if (component == null) {
    component = DaggerDemoApplication_ApplicationComponent
        .builder()
        .clockModule(new ClockModule())
        .build();
  }
}

public void setComponent(DemoComponent component) {
  this.component = component;
}

public DemoComponent component() {
  return component;
}
```

And modify it in the test case

```
@Before
  public void setUp() {
    Instrumentation instrumentation = InstrumentationRegistry.getInstrumentation();
    DemoApplication app
        = (DemoApplication) instrumentation.getTargetContext().getApplicationContext();
    TestComponent component = DaggerMainActivityTest_TestComponent.builder()
        .mockClockModule(new MockClockModule())
        .build();
    app.setComponent(component);
    component.inject(this);
  }
```